# Does mvn sonar instrument analysed classes

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

What exactly does `mvn sonar:sonar`? does it instrument classes to measure code coverage? or it just sends sources to the server?

to sum it up: can i safely do `mvn verify sonar:sonar deploy` and be sure my package is not instrumented in any way?

Comment: It runs this tool: http://www.sonarsource.org/ However, you would have to configure it and do a first run, install ruleset, and so on in order to get something from this tool.

Answer (score 2):

@piotek, in any case it's highly recommended (see Sonar documentation) to do the analysis in two steps :

- First : 'mvn clean install' or 'mvn verify deploy' in your case
- Second : 'mvn sonar:sonar'

And to answer to your question, Sonar is analysing both the java source code and the bytecode. Moreover in case of usage of Cobertura, the source code is instrumented.